# Crash on [SLComposeViewController initWithExtension:requestedServiceType:]_block_invoke + 84

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios11, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'am getting some crashes on `SLComposeViewController`

```
Crashed: com.apple.extension.global-state-queue
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18167cbb4 objc_loadWeakRetained + 156
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18167cd64 objc_copyWeak + 24
2  Social                         0x1933abdbc __66-[SLComposeViewController initWithExtension:requestedServiceType:]_block_invoke + 84
3  Foundation                     0x182b30b04 __85-[NSExtension _completeRequestReturningItems:forExtensionContextWithUUID:completion:]_block_invoke + 108
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x181ad1088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x181ad1048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x181adae48 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x181adb7d8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x181adc200 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 400
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x181ae44a0 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x181d76fe0 _pthread_wqthread + 932
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x181d76c30 start_wqthread + 4
```

**Looks like to me like the reference got lost somehow? any idea?**

I don't do anything special

```
- (void)presentTwitterShareWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

    if (url == nil) {
        return;
    }

    SLComposeViewController * cvc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [cvc addURL:url];

    [cvc setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

        if (SLComposeViewControllerResultDone == result) {

            [[Analytics shared] trackWithCategory:@"Web" action:@"Tap" label:@"Share - Twitter"];

        }

    }];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:cvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Note: it looks to me iOS11 related as i cannot recall having this issue before, also it was not tracked besides iOS11

Answer (score 1):

`SLServiceTypeTwitter` is removed in iOS 11. You need to use Twitter's own share solution to implement this functionality.

See this page for information about migrating to `TwitterKit` from your current solution: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/migrate-social-framework

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the view controller is accessed inside of the library after the view controller is deallocated. I guess it's a extension's bug.

Preserving the view controller might work for a workaround.

```
- (void)presentTwitterShareWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

    if (url == nil) {
        return;
    }

    __block SLComposeViewController * cvc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [cvc addURL:url];

    [cvc setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

        if (SLComposeViewControllerResultDone == result) {

            [[Analytics shared] trackWithCategory:@"Web" action:@"Tap" label:@"Share - Twitter"];

        }

    }];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:cvc animated:YES completion:^{
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cvc = nil;
        });
    }];
}
```